# How to prove A is not bounded above and find Inf A?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, discrete-mathematics

[question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYwVA.jpg)

For part (a), I was able to solve it using Bernoulli's inequality (if that's correct), and saying that you can chooce n to be arbitrarily large, so there does not exist an upper bound.

For (b) I know how to prove that 0 is a lower bound, but how do you prove it is the inf (Greatest lower bound), and how owuld you use part (a) in this question?

Comment: Show $a_n \ge 0$ and $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use binomial theorem, just the well known Bernoulli's inequality: if $A>-1$ then $(1+A)^{n}\,\geq\, 1+nA$. Setting $A=a-1$ which is greater than $-1$ for $a>1$ we get $a^{n}\geq\,1+n(a-1)$ and since $n(a-1)\to +\infty$ then $a^{n}\to +\infty$.

If $a<1$ then $\dfrac{1}{a}>1$ and $\dfrac{1}{a^{n}}\to +\infty$ hence $a^{n}\to 0^{+}$ and clearly $infA=0$.

Comment: Thank you! But what about for part (b)? I was able to use Bernoulli's inequality for (a), but I didn't know how you would prove that inf A = 0. It was easy to show that a^n > 0, but how do you show it is the infimum?

Comment: I added part (b).

Comment: Do you want a rigorous proof that if $\dfrac{1}{a^{n}}\to +\infty$ then $a^{n}\to 0$? I can do it but I think it is very straightforward! By the way, an upvote would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Yes that would be great, thank you!

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $a^{n}<\epsilon$ is equivalent to $\dfrac{1}{a^{n}}>\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$. But $\dfrac{1}{a^{n}}\to +\infty$ means that for each $M$ and hence for $M=1/\epsilon$ there is an $n_{0}$ such that $n>n_{0}$ implies $\dfrac{1}{a^{n}}>M=\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$, hence $a^{n}<\epsilon$ for $n>n_{0}$ and we are done!